# Kubernetes Ingress behind Cloud Load Balancer

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-controller, hetzner-cloud

When using an Ingress Controller in Kubernetes the Ingress service is usually exposed via Load Balancer. Now I’m trining to understand on how this exactly works.
As I understand it the Ingress Controller is just running as an Pod like any other app and gets exposed via the Load Balancer.
When configuring the external load balancer what target do I set, the Worker nodes or the master nodes, or does this even matter because I use a Service and then it’s automatically internally Load balanced?

I try to get this Right so I can setup a Kubernetes Cluster in the Hetzner Cloud, because it has no managed service I need to do basically everything on my on but it provides the services to theoretically host a full HA cluster.
So the plan is to have for the beginning 3 Master Nodes and 2/3 Worker Nodes and an Managed Load Balancer in front of everything.
I thought about having 2 Cloud Networks one lb-network for the master nodes and the load balancer and a second one cluster network for the master and worker nodes. But with that approach every incoming traffic needs to get through the Masters to get terminated at the Ingress Controller which is running on the Worker, I like that approach because it allows me to use fewer targets on the Load Balancer to save some money also I could mostly isolate the workers from incoming traffic on a network level. Is that approach possible and even best practices or what do you recommend?